# Multiplying x values with factor 2 (Python plotting)

Tags: python, plot, multiplication

I have a 150x150 matrix. For plotting I would like each x value to be multiplied by 2. However, with my code below I get the error 'x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (300,) and (150,)".

```
x_1 = [*range(0, im1.shape[0], 1)] 
x = 2 * x_1      #deltaT is 2 min
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that `2 * x_1` will double your list, and does not multiply its elemetns. You can simply multiply your array using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np
x_1 = np.array([*range(0, im1.shape[0], 1)])
x = 2 * x_1      #deltaT is 2 min
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Now, if the `x` and `y` are in the same shape, you  will not have any problem.

Comment: thank you! That did not work unfortunately... Now it tells me that the * infront of range is an invalid syntax... and without it I just get an empty plot

Comment: @Laura That's kinda weird. What does `im1.shape[0]` return? if it's a number, this code will work fine.

Comment: yes it's a number! Still it doesn't work.. However, I found a workaround by doing it like this:

x =[*range(0, im1.shape[0], 1)] ;
x = [i * 2 for i in x]